# JavaScript-clearRect()-pendant for ActionScript?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, canvas

Is there a ActionScript-version of JavaScript's Canvas.clearRect()?

I only know graphics.drawRect(...) which allows me draw but not remove rectangles.

If there is no such method in ActionScript, how can I emulate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not an equivalent in ActionScript to clearRect. If you need to do that, then you may want to have multiple sprites, and draw to them separately. That would allow you to adjust z-order, and to remove sections.

If you need to cut out a section of a shape, then you can use drawPath.

mike

Comment: Mike, I concur with user286149. I see no easy way to do this. I think drawPath will make donuts, but not punch a hole in an existing bitmap, true? Perhaps there could be a special "color" that deletes pixels.

Comment: In caso of a BitmapData, you could use the setPixel and other API to clear a region of the bitmap.. however the question was about the graphics API, which is not like a bitmap, but more like a collection of vector drawing instructions, so you cant "blit pixels" but "draw graphic primitives" such as rectangles, lines or circles.

Answer (score 0):

graphics.clear();

Comment: That won't help because graphics.clear() deletes the whole canvas. What I was asking for was a method to remove one specific rectangle from the canvas.

Comment: drawRect is creating bitmap data, not display objects. So if you draw two rectangles, you have a canvas full of pixels. You can't "remove" one of them, short of redrawing over that section or using multiple Sprites as Mike Chambers said.

Comment: It's interesting then that removing specific pixels on a HTML5 canvas is possible (through JavaScript)

Comment: I agree (commented above too). You probably have to use a mask to do what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Not very intuitive, but, *in the same fill operation*, redrawing again on the same pixel will actually "cut it". So, for example:

```
graphics.clear();
graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
graphics.drawRect(0, 0, width, height);
graphics.drawRect(10, 10, width - 10, height - 10);
graphics.endFill();
```

Should actually draw an external border of 10 pixels, leaving the rest of the object transparent. However, once you finish the fill operation, AFAIK there is no way to clear an area without clearing all the graphics of the DisplayObject.